# How can I get log4net to write to a filename based on the class that instantiated the logger?

Tags: c#, log4net

This is my dilemma. I have a `RollingFileAppender`. I have a `BufferingForwardingAppender`. The forwarding appender writes to the file appender. My file appender needs a file to write to. I want the file to be named as such `%Called Assembly Type%log.txt`, where %Called Assembly Type% is the called assembly type (gasp!)

I'm intending to use this as follows:

Calling from a service called "`OkilyDokily`":

```
var log4NetLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetMyAssemblyName());
log4NetLogger.LogInfo("Toodleoo");
```

Calling from a service called "`Neighborinos`":

```
var log4NetLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetMyAssemblyName());
log4NetLogger.LogInfo("Toodleoo");
```

I expect to have 2 log files, one named `OkilyDokilylog.txt` and one named `Neighborinoslog.txt`

Is there a way to do this in log4net? Is my `BufferingForwardingAppender` going to be an issue? I have tried this configuration but `%logger` is simply translating to the string `logger` :(

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
        <conversionPattern value="C:\testlogs\%logger log.txt" />
    </file>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <countDirection value="1"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-8level %-21date{M/d/yyyy H:m:ss} %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: This is a good question of its own merit, but I especially like reading questions that have a little character to them.  And Ned Flanders isn't a bad choice at all for that, so +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this small tidbit might help you out:  you need to override the **RollingFileAppender** and after modifying the `File` property, invoke the `ActivateOptions` method, like below:

```
var myPath = "C:\\";
var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MySpecificAssembly).Name);
XmlConfigurator.Configure();

var rfa = (RollingFileAppender)LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders()
    .First(c => c.Name == "RollingFileAppender");

rfa.File = myPath + typeof(MySpecificAssembly).Name + ".log";
rfa.ActivateOptions();
```

Comment: Thank you, although I was hoping there is a way to do this via the configuration file. I'd rather not have to dive into code unless I realllllly need to.

Comment: @Stefan: yeah, this is one of those small areas where the configurator just falls short...!